ConnectionError: Login failed for user '' when using msnodesqlv8 driver in Node.js
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js application while attempting to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database using the mssql/msnodesqlv8 package. Whenever I try to establish a connection, I receive the following error:

ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

Here's how I'm configuring my connection:
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const config = {
    server: '192.168.43.125\\sqlexpress',
    database: 'test',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            trustedConnection: true // Using Windows authentication
        }
    },
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
        encrypt: false,
    }
};

async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        console.log('Connection established successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Connection failed:', err);
    }
}

connectToDatabase();

I've ensured that:
The server address and database name are correct.
Windows authentication is being used.
The user running the script has appropriate permissions on the SQL Server.
Despite this, I'm still encountering the login failure error. Can someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

For security reasons SQL Server will never tell a client exactly why a login attempt failed, just that it did. If you check the targeted SQL Server instance's ERRORLOG can you find the related Error 18456 Login Failed messages? If you compare the State number reported in those messages against the State numbers listed at MSSQLSERVER_18456 it will tell you exactly why the login failed.
